# Axis2 - return Java class

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis

Following a short tutorial http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200603/WSComplexTypes.html (axis 1.4 however afaik) I want to create a web service method that will return a specific Java class. I'm using Eclipse Juno, Axis2 1.6.2 and Tomcat 6 Server.

The class looks like:

```
public class Person implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public int id;
public String name;
    public String surname;
}
```

The web method looks like

```
public Person getPersonDetails(){
    Person result = new Person();
    result.id = 1;
    result.name = "test";
    result.surname = "test2";
    return result;
}
```

Then after generating the WSDL and deploying the web service, my WSDL file looks like:
...

```
  <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://mycrm/xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified"> 
  <xs:complexType name="Person"> 
  <xs:sequence/> 
  </xs:complexType></xs:schema>
```

...

```
  <xs:element name="getPersonDetails"> 
  <xs:complexType> <xs:sequence/> </xs:complexType> </xs:element> 
  <xs:element name="getPersonDetailsResponse"> -<xs:complexType> -<xs:sequence>          
  <xs:element name="return" type="ax21:Person" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>         
  </xs:sequence> </xs:complexType> </xs:element>
```

From what I understand, the Person class is not mapped in any way in the web service. Testing the call returns only soap response looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
 <ns:getPersonDetailsResponse xmlns:ns="http://mycrm">
  <ns:return xmlns:ax21="http://mycrm/xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax21:Person"/>
 </ns:getPersonDetailsResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So my question is:
- is there a simple step I'm forgetting about that will map the class in WSDL so I can get the data returned properly
- returning data like this is wrong - do it XML or JSON style? (I want to use this web service in Adobe Flex project)

Comment: have you defined getters for Person's attributes?

Comment: Why do you need getters when everything is public?

Comment: because that's what is used to generate a <sequence>?

Comment: Thx a lot - adding getters to the classes totally resolved the problem - I felt that I was missing a pretty simple thing :D